# PHP insert date into mysql database with mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I would like to be able to add children into a database, which are connected to their parents (who has a member id MID). I believe that the error lies within the date format (atleast that's what I believe), I have also tried to use strtotime($dob), however this didn't change anything.

```
   $name = htmlspecialchars($_GET['Name']);
   $dob = $_GET['DOB'];
   $newDOB = date("Y-m-d", $dob);
   $mid = $_GET['mid'];

   if(isset($_GET['Name'], $_GET['DOB'], $_GET['mid']))
       $alert = true;
   if(!empty($name) && !empty($newDOB) && !empty($mid))
       add_family_member($mid, $newDOB, $name);
```

The function that adds the member:

```
function add_family_member($mid, $dob, $name)
{
    global $con;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Children(MID, DOB, Name) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
    if($stmt)
    {
        $b = $stmt->bind_param("iss", $mid, $dob, $name);
        if($b)
        {
            $e = $stmt->execute();
            if($e)
                return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Also if needed this is the form used for entering the data:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="addmembers">
    <table class="infotable">
      <tr>
        <td>Navn: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Name" required> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Fødselsdato: </td>
        <td><input type="date" name="DOB" required></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Tilføj"><input type="reset" value="Reset"></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Can you share error you getting.  Your code is bit messy

Comment: I don't get an actual error, which is why I intially thought the error came from mysql inserting the date.

Comment: maybe problem is here `$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);` Its not working. Use `$stmt = $con->prepare($sql) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));` to check error.

Answer (score 0):

The `date()` function works on a time() value and not on a string, so you need to convert the entered date to a time value first before converting it using `date()`

```
$newDOB = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dob));
```

Comment: I tried this before, but this isn't the issue. Still doesn't work.

Comment: I do not believe you can pass any value via $_GET that will work with the `date()` function. Please do a `var_dump($dob, $newDOB)` just after you do the conversion, and show us what the result is!